# Are Eaton main breakers compatible challenger replacements?

Tags: electrical

I have a challenger main panel. I know that I can replace the circuit breakers with Eaton BR breakers. But what about the main 200A breaker?

This is a special order item so I am trying the ascertain compatibility. Challenger main breakers appear to be "QFP" type, but that type isn't listed in the official compatibility document.

Comment: That is a question for Eaton or an Eaton dealer.  These manufacturers have a perfectly competent support network both direct and through full service dealers.  Some just think big box and mail order is cheaper.  This is illusionary.

Comment: Can you post photos of the labeling on said main breaker, and on the inside of the panel for that matter?